# How to remove (not visible) a swf when a diiferent swf is clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, video, air, flash

I have created a Adobe Air mobile app in which two swfs are placed over the

playing video as following image-

[image: Main video and two transparent swf]

but when I clicked on left swf a video starts playing like this-

[image: Left swf video]

but when I clicked the right swf the left swf appear over it-

[image: Right swf video]

My codes for the this is given below-

```
               var newSerial1:SerialElement = new SerialElement();
                var newSerial2:SerialElement = new SerialElement();
                newSerial1.addChild(new DurationElement(5));
                newSerial1.addChild(Linear);
                newSerial2.addChild(new DurationElement(5));
                newSerial2.addChild(Linear1);
                parallelElement.addChild(videoElement);
                parallelElement.addChild(newSerial1);
                parallelElement.addChild(newSerial2);
                serialElement.addChild(parallelElement);
                serialElement.addChild(new DurationElement(5));
```

I think the parallelElement put the video on bottom layer and right swf on

middle and left swf on the uppermost layer. But I did not want the swf appear

on the top of video.

Is there any way that when I clicked a layer it became the uppermost layer

or any other way that the uppermost layered swf does not appear when clicked on the

middle layered swf or any other way that swf does the appear the video when

video is playing or `layoutmetadata` can be used for that purpose.

Comment: set `movieclipName.alpha=0` for those swfs.

Comment: @RajneeshGaikwad  I have added the `alpha` but nothing changed. I think the problem is `ParallelElement` which place the video and two swfs parallel to video and the swfs are transparent so when middle swf clicked the upper swf appear over it. Is `index` property can put both swf in same layer?